# FOSUser Bundle Login Not Working with Ramsey UUID After Upgrading

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, uuid

I updated the symfony application from 4.0 to 4.4 everything is working fine except when login into ma dashboard i am getting this error `Could not convert database value "11ea3053-6c85-df5a-a..." to Doctrine Type uuid_binary_ordered_time. Expected format: UuidV1` 
if I downgrade the the `ramsey/uuid-doctrine` version everything works fine. 
Current Symfony verssion `4.4`

Same User is able to login using rest API with Basic Auth. Here is my id param in `User.php` which is using the UUID. Thanks In advance.

```
 /**
 * @var Uuid
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="uuid_binary_ordered_time", unique=true)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidOrderedTimeGenerator")
 */
protected $id;


 /**
 * @return string
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id->getHex();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

so i found the solution for above problem. actually, the problem was with symfony serialization and deserialization. Everything works fine except the login of admin panel which is using session for storing user data is override the serialize and deserialize method of  Security `User Class User.php` and everything works fine.
Main thing is that during the serialization i have to convert my uuid to string and during deserialization i have to convert back the string uuid. here is the code in my `User.php` Entity class.

```
 public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->password,
        $this->salt,
        $this->usernameCanonical,
        $this->username,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->id->toString(),
        $this->email,
        $this->emailCanonical,
    ));
}

public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    $data = unserialize($serialized);

    if (13 === count($data)) {
        // Unserializing a User object from 1.3.x
        unset($data[4], $data[5], $data[6], $data[9], $data[10]);
        $data = array_values($data);
    } elseif (11 === count($data)) {
        // Unserializing a User from a dev version somewhere between 2.0-alpha3 and 2.0-beta1
        unset($data[4], $data[7], $data[8]);
        $data = array_values($data);
    }
    $data[5] = UuidV1::fromString($data[5]);
    list(
        $this->password,
        $this->salt,
        $this->usernameCanonical,
        $this->username,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
        $this->emailCanonical
        ) = $data;
}
```